# Ffmpeg Ignore stream if it doesn't exist

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to convert files to .mp3 and extract cover images from the metadata.

This works fine for files that have cover images, files that don't throw the error:

> Output #1 does not contain any stream

```
ffmpeg -i kalimba.mp3 -y test.mp3 -acodec copy test.jpg
```

How can I tell ffmpeg to just ignore streams if they don't exist and continue converting to .mp3 if no cover image exists in the metadata?

Answer (score 0):

First you should check what streams are provided in the file. You can do it with tool [ffprobe](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html). Then you run `ffmpeg` to copy one or two streams.

```
if [ -n "`ffprobe -show_streams -v quiet kalimba.mp3  | grep '^\[streams\.stream\.1\]'`" ] ; then
  #  the file has 2 streams
  ffmpeg -i kalimba.mp3 -y test.mp3 -acodec copy test.jpg
else
  # no cover image
  ffmpeg -i kalimba.mp3 -y test.mp3 -acodec copy
fi
```